# Удаления элемента JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

В моем Android приложение приходит `JSONArray`. Примерно выглядит вот так:

```
[19,145,51]
```

При определенных обстоятельств мне приходится удалять один из элементов массива. Сейчас делаю это так:

```
jsonAr.remove(i);
```

Но метод `remove` работает начиная с API 19. Мне же нужно это делать на 17. Как можно удалить элемент так чтобы API 17 тоже понимал что к чему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не нужно оставлять ссылку на оригинальный массив и позволительно создать новый, то так:

```
public static JSONArray remove(final JSONArray from, final int index) throws JSONException {
    final JSONArray res = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0, count = from.length(); i < count; i++) {
        if(index != i)
            res.put(from.get(i));
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Была такая мысль но казалось странной. Но я так и сделаю

Comment: @user8978194 не думаю, что есть способ удалить из оригинального массива до версии 19. Все решения для старых версий на основе копирования сделаны.